# I woud like to graft a different variety of cherry onto an existing over-tall pin cherry tree

Tags: grafting, cherries

Tree is nearly 40' tall with approximately 12" trunk. Prolific producer of small tart cherries, but all are out of reach. The nearest branch is 16' off the ground.
• Can I graft other varieties of cherry into the trunk? What time of year is best to graft? Neighbors have very successful Queen Ann variety.
• Should I cut branches from this tree and graft lower down?
• We are on the Pacific Coast, zone 9a 20°F to 25°F